# "Остаётся не расшифровано"

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Разве можно сказать "само слово остаётся не расшифровано" вместо "остаётся нерасшифрованным" (прочитал в книжке)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ответ исправлен.**

"Само слово остаётся не расшифровано".

Думаю, что это неверно составленная фраза, так как  форма связки не соответствует форме именной части.

1) Само слово не расшифровано / было  не расшифровано (незнаменательная связка);  2) Само слово остаётся/оставалось  нерасшифрованным (полузнаменательная связка).

Знаменательная связка    **не сочетается** с предикативной формой краткого причастия.

**Дополнение (почему надо использовать полную форму причастия)**

1) **Краткое причастие** выражает предикативные значения (время, род, число) **самостоятельно**, для этого ему не нужна связка: запись расшифрована.

2) Незнаменательная **связка «быть»** в форме прошедшего времени может при этом присутствовать, но она обозначает  **завершенность** действия до определенного времени: запись была расшифрована.

3) Полузнаменательная **связка «оставаться»**  также выражает предикативные значения,  и в этом случае **еще одна  предикативность, выраженная кратким причастием,  оказывается лишней, а предложение смотрится некорректно** (в нем как бы присутствуют два сказуемых): Запись  остается/оставалась не расшифрована.  Запись считается/считалась расшифрована. Вопрос остается/оставался открыт.

Поэтому  в качестве именной части используется причастие  **в полной форме**.

Comment: Спасибо! Вот и мне как-то так казалось.

Comment: Полное непонимание грамматики, Вы уж простите. Здесь "расшифровано" - краткая форма причастия - и вопрос только в том, допустимо ли использование краткой формы в данном случае, т.е. может ли данная конструкция трактоваться как предикатив.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос интересный. 
Тут смешиваются две грамматические проблемы.
Во-первых, является ли слово "оставаться" полной заменой "быть" в роли связки при предикате, во-вторых, допустим ли такой фокус с раздельно написанным отрицанием.

На первое ответ положительный. Давайте заменим. "Фраза была понятна". "Фраза осталась понятна". "Он был доволен", "Он остался доволен". Проблем нет. Специально взял два примера на мужской и женский род, средний путает.

А вот с "не" - тут путано. Заменяем: "Само слово было не расшифровано". Похоже, что "не" - надо писать или слитно или перед "было". Иначе смысл теряется.

Значит, имеем "само слово остаётся нерасшифровано". Но это весьма сомнительная конструкция с точки зрения правил "**не** с кратким  причастием". Такое ощущение, что именно в этой сомнительности причина неприятия исходной фразы.

*Итак, по первому впечатлению такая фраза является стилистически неверной из-за наличия в ней отрицания перед кратким причастием в роли предиката. Правильной была бы фраза "Слово не осталось расшифровано"  или "Слово осталось расшифровано" (правда, тут смысл ускользает в обоих случаях из-за семантики "осталось" , что не дает возможности говорить о стилистической правильности).*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Ух, и напрягло же вдумываться в смысл обоих ответов!)) *Похоже, что "не" - надо писать или слитно или перед не "было".* Наверно, перед "было" "не" вы имели в виду?

Comment: Да, извините. Хотел выразиться попонятнее, но получилось "как всегда!. )))

Comment: А вообще я обычно правлю свои плюхи, через какое-то время, когда чувствую, что нагородил, а сил или времени проверить сразу нету.