# Полная и краткая формы причастия в именном сказуемом

Tags: грамматика

В качестве именной части при наличии полузнаменательных связок **обычно используются полные формы причастий или прилагательных**:

Европа остаётся/оставалась  **разделённой** на национальные рынки. Пока остаётся/оставался **открытым** следующий вопрос. Судьба остальных четырёх человек остаётся/оставалась пока **неизвестной**.

**Может ли   в этом случае  применяться  краткая форма?** При каких условиях это возможно, а при каких не допускается?

Это пример использования краткой формы: Писемский, по-видимому, оставался доволен романом.
Два варианта: Маннергейм оставался верен присяге. И все-таки он оставался верным правилу.

Comment: В справочнике по Литературному редактированию ( Розенталь, Д.Э.) , сказано, что полные формы прилагательных, в отличии от кратких,  в значении сказуемого не обладает способностью синтаксического управления. Встречающиеся в художественной литературе конструкции с наличием управляемых слов при полной форме связаны с просторечной окраской, например: Я на такую тяжесть уже не способный (В. Кожевников).

Comment: Но пример ''И все-таки он оставался верным правилу '' вряд ли назовешь просторечным.

Comment: И еще: вас интересует краткие формы прилагательных или причастий?

Comment: Серж, этот вопрос как бы продолжение вопроса , который недавно обсуждался http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/421126/Остаётся-не-расшифровано/421127#421127 . Вопрос оказался сложным, а ответы не очень ясными. В этом примере  имеется связка "остается" и отрицательная частица НЕ. Меня интересуют только варианты с такой связкой   и краткой формой причастий и прилагательных (и без частицы НЕ).

Comment: Я пытаюсь найти что-нибудь с этой связкой, но пока ничего нет.

Comment: Связка должна быть полузнаменательной или знаменательной (стать, являться, считаться, называться и др.). Любая, кроме "быть".

Comment: Со связкой ''стать" я нашел информацию. Постараюсь сегодня дать вам ссылку.

Comment: Ссылку, к сожалению, дать, не могу. Здесь не помещается. Но вы прочитайте Справочник по Литературному редактированию ( Розенталь, Д.Э.). В краткости отвечу. При связках стать, становиться, оказаться преобладает творительный предикативный. При связке быть возможны и краткая форма, и творительный предикативный полной формы.

Comment: Советую также прочитать: Александр Николаевич Гвоздев.  [Очерки по стилистике русского языка. § 399.СКАЗУЕМОЕ И СИНОНИМИКА ВЫРАЖЕНИЯ СКАЗУЕМОГО](http://refdb.ru/look/2518884.html)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, полная форма причастий и прилагательных в именной части составного именного сказуемого, в отличие от краткой формы,  придаёт высказыванию некий устаревший оттенок: оставался довольным - оставался доволен; оставался верным - оставался верен.

Answer (score 0):

Пл памяти, могу чего-то упустить и даже перепутать, так что уточнения и критика принимается.

Причастия в СИС обычно используются в полной форме, прилагательные - в краткой. 
Примеры иного обычно просторечия.

В случаях, когда причастие омонимично прилагательному, обе формы возможны.

В сочетании с глаголом "быть" также возможны обе формы того и другого (с небольшой стилистической разницей).

Вот вкратце.

Где-то видел примеры исключений, сейчас уж и не вспомню. Но они единичные.